# WordUtils.capitalizeFully from commons-text

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to use WordUtils.capitalizeFully from commons-text. 
The current version I am using is version 1.1 below, which is working fine

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I upgrade to version 1.2, WordUtils.capitalizeFully doesn't work. Why is this so ?

Comment: You are looking at the release notes for `1.0-beta-1`

Comment: Thanks for the correction @smac. I have edited the question now.